# Attaching a Tether to another robot's base_link in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf, simulation, ros-noetic

I am trying to simulate a tether attached to my robot in gazebo. I am describing the robot and the tether using `urdf xacro` files. My tether is modeled as a chain of links generated using a recursive macro connected by `revolute` joints. It is imported in the urdf file for my robot (named `robot`.) My next step is to connect this tether to another robot called  `tank_tether_connect` which is spawned separately from a `launch` file. My next step is to connect the loose end of the tether to a link inside `tank_tether_connect`'s urdf file called `tank_tether_link`. The way I tried going about it is just creating a new joint that connects the last link of my tether to `tank_tether_link`. Here is the code for that joint:

```
<!-- joint to connect the last link to the tank connect -->
<joint name="last_link_joint_tank" type="revolute">
      <parent link="link_last"/>
      <child link="tank_tether_connect/tank_tether_link"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 ${link_length}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
      <limit lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" effort="2" velocity="0.1"/>
</joint>
```

`link_last` is the last link in my tether. For reference, here is the urdf file for `tank_tether_connect` as well:

```
<robot name="tank_tether_connect" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <link name="tank_tether_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="500"/>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.025"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
        </inertial>
        
    </link>
</robot>
```

Whenever I run this code, I always get an error saying:

```
[ERROR] [1710545225.274118052]: Failed to build tree: child link [tank_tether_connect/tank_tether_link] of joint [last_link_joint_tank] not found
```

I reckoned this is a namespace issue so I tried referencing it with and without its parent robot's name. However, nothing seemed to work. If I can get some help on how to reference a link in another robot that'd be really appreciated. Thanks :)